# How can I download all txt files that has been created in the last 60 seconds from my SFTP Server?

Tags: c#, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"filepath")
    {
        Filter = "*.txt",
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName,
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };

    fileSystemWatcher.Created += OnActionOccurOnFolderPath;

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void OnActionOccurOnFolderPath(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ChangeType);
    Console.WriteLine(e.Name);
    Upload.upload();
}
```

This uploads any txt file that has been created in a specified path to the SFTP Server.

The server will generate a report about whether the upload and file processing was successful.
This usually takes about 2-3 minutes.
I then check with a timer every 60 seconds if there has been a new report created.

First I get a list of the files in the directory:

```
RemoteDirectoryInfo directoryInfo = session.ListDirectory(remotePath);
```

Here I select the latest file:

```
RemoteFileInfo latest =
    directoryInfo.Files
        .Where(file => !file.IsDirectory)
        .OrderByDescending(file => file.LastWriteTime)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

I go on with downloading the file to check it for some parameters.

```
session.GetFileToDirectory(latest.FullName, localPath);
```

But whenever I upload multiple files, there will be multiple reports but I can only download the latest one.

My intention is that I want to download everything that has been created in the last 60 seconds.
This needs to be done while the upload of new data can still be assured.

So I suppose that the code above for finding `latest` need to be changed in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download files created in the last minute, use [file mask time constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time) `>=60S`:

```cs
session.GetFilesToDirectory(remoteDirectory, localDirectory, "*>=60S").Check();
```